# Stretch a SVG image along the x-axis

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm looking to stretch my SVG image along the horizontal axis, which is acting as a background for some HTML divs. It is a simple bar that takes up the middle third horizontally :

[image]

It must not move on the vertical, and when horizontal is stretched, the image also must stretch so that the bar takes up the middle third.

Currently if I stretch horizontally, it maintains its vertical position which is good, but the SVG does not take up a third but maintains its original width:

[image]

Here is the React code :

```
function BackgroundSVG() {

    let outerDiv = {
        position:"relative",
        border: "3px solid red",
    }

    let svgStyle = {
        position:"absolute",
        top:"0px",
        border: "3px solid pink",
        zIndex: -1,

        width: "100%",
        height: "200px"
    }
    return (
        <div style={outerDiv}>
            <div>Lorem ipsum .......</div>
            <svg style={svgStyle}
                 viewBox={`0 0 ${600} ${200} `}
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d={`M ${200} ${100} H ${400}`} strokeWidth={12} stroke="blue"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is a code pen

https://codepen.io/oliverwatkins/pen/MWqWmQz

How do I stretch the image along the x-axis, while preserving things on the y-axis?

I have tried to play around with the widths and heights but that does not seem to work. I assume that if I keep width at 100% and height at a 200px that this would solve the problem.

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio="none"`on image may help.

Comment: i just tried and it works. Strange... i tried it before but it didnt work. I think maybe with my sizings were different

Comment: if you answer the question with your comment, i will give you the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `preserveAspectRatio` attribute value is `xMidYMid meet`
so that browser try to maintain image aspect ratio.

For stretching SVG image, we need to set
`preserveAspectRatio="none"`